# Riverpod ProviderListener - 'StateNotifierProvider<Auth, bool>' can't be assigned to 'ProviderBase<Object, StateController<bool>>'

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-hooks

I'm trying to use a ProviderListener from Riverpod to listen to my authProvider and control the page displayed if a user is authorized or not.  I'm getting the error:

error: The argument type 'StateNotifierProvider<Auth, bool>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderBase<Object, StateController>'.

The error shows up on the: provider: authProvider, inside the ProviderListener

I'm wondering if it's due to the update on StateNotifierProvider?

I would like to know how to use the ProviderListener better even if there's a better way to handle the authorization flow (I'm VERY open to feedback and criticism and greatly appreciate any time a person can take to help). I cut out non-relevant code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class Auth extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  Auth() : super(false);

  void setAuth(bool auth) {
    state = auth;
  }
}

final authProvider = StateNotifierProvider<Auth, bool>((ref) => Auth());

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulHookWidget {
  // const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _fbMyApp = Firebase.initializeApp();

  Widget route = SplashScreen();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ProviderListener<StateController<bool>>(
      provider: authProvider,
      onChange: (context, auth) {
        if (auth.state = true) {
          route = HomeScreen();
        } else {
          route = SplashScreen();
        }
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
              home: route,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `StateController` from `ProviderListener`, leave only the type (bool in this case)

```
return ProviderListener<bool>(
  provider: authProvider, //this will read the state of your provider (a bool state)
  onChange: (context, auth) {
    if (auth) { //remove setter auth = true, it doesn't make sense to set a value inside an if
      route = HomeScreen();
    } else {
      route = SplashScreen();
    }
  },
  child: MaterialApp(
          home: route,
);
```

This way you're reading the state of your `StateNotifier`

Comment: I tried that first.  That has the error: error: The setter 'state' isn't defined for the type 'bool'.          I would have thought state = auth sets that in the statenotifier

Comment: My bad, inside if it would be == to evaluate a boolean, in this case if(auth) should be enough

Comment: ProviderListener<T> has been deprecated and replaced with WidgetRef.listen<T>

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to sort of work by changing to:

```
return ProviderListener<StateNotifier<bool>>(
      provider: authProvider.notifier,
```

it's giving me a non-breaking error of:
info: The member 'state' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:state_notifier/state_notifier.dart'. (invalid_use_of_protected_member)

and not working properly - the state isn't being updated when I'm using a context.read

```
context.read(authProvider.notifier).state = true;
```

So it's buggy but not fully broken.  At least it's some progress.  I would still love help and any feedback anyone wants to give!